# How to replace character in the string using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to replace every `x` in the end of line or string and behind every letters except `aiueo` with `nya`.
Expected input and output:

Input: `bapakx`

Output: `bapaknya`

I've tried this one:

```
String myString = "bapakx";
String regex = "[^aiueo]x(\\s|$)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
if(m.find()){
    myString = m.replaceAll("nya");
}
```

But the output is not `bapaknya` but `bapanya`. The `k` character is also replaced. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get consonant back Use a **zero width** lookbehind in your regex as:

```
String regex = "(?<=[^aiueo])x(?=\\s|$)";
```

Here `(?<=[^aiueo])` will only assert presence of `consonant` before `x` but won't match it.

Alternatively you can use capture groups:

```
String regex = "([^aiueo])x(\\s|$)";
```

and use it as:

```
myString = m.replaceAll("$1nya");
```

Comment: Ahh, got it. Thank you